# Display a text file in two boxes, one in plain text and the other converted to hex

Tags: c#

I have a form with two text boxes, in one I want to show a .txt file in text format and in the other text box I want to show the same text but in hex. I have no idea how to do this as programming isn't a strong point of mine. Also it has to be in whole columns and the hex box should show the value of each character in the form `0xNN`. In case anyone recognizes this [I did ask a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371267/help-needed-in-using-visual-c-sharp-express-editon) earlier today, but have since progressed with some of it. I'm using Visual C# Express Edition 2008 obviously dealing with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char character in File.ReadAllText("input.txt").ToCharArray())
        { //convert the string to array of bytes
            sb.Append("0x"+      ///"0x" prefix
               ((int)character). //convert char to int
               ToString("X2"));  //generate string with two hex digit.
            sb.Append("\n");         //new line after each converted char
        }

        TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString(); //set text box text
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to convert the text to a byte[],

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textFromFile);
```

and use `BitConverter.ToString()` to build a hex list of the byte[].

```
string hexListing = BitConverter.ToString(bytes)
```

Comment: How do you convert the text to a numeric representation, and then to a byte[]?  That's non-trivial for a neophyte.

Comment: @Robert: FGITW -- Post the overview, then lookup (and repost) the details.